# asp:placeholder content update with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have a asp:placeholder which keeps a literal text on the load of document. With ajax, I need to update the literal. I digged some, but found no answer.

Here is my asmx code:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="yoklama" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; padding-right: 17px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Yoklama Kayıtları</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="tbl_pdcr_main"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn dark btn-outline" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <%--<button type="button" class="btn green">Save changes</button>--%>
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdf_pdcr_reg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Staff/PDX.aspx/GetPDCRRecords',
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: '{r_id:' + yil + '}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#<%=lbl_pdcx_y_gec.ClientID%>').text(data.d.YGec);
        $('#<%=lbl_pdcx_y_msiz.ClientID%>').text(data.d.YMaz);
        $('#<%=lbl_pdcx_y_rap.ClientID%>').text(data.d.YRap);
        $('#<%=lbl_pdcx_y_terk.ClientID%>').text(data.d.YTerk);
        $('#<%=lbl_pdcx_y_diger.ClientID%>').text(data.d.YDiger);

        $('#<%=tbl_pdcr_main.ClientID%>').replaceWith(data.d.PDCRLog);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Appreciate for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the FACT that the PlaceHolder doesn't render any HTML, your id search can then not find it.

You can try using a [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with the ASP.NET Web Forms framework I'd suggest to not relay on `Id`s as the framework adds some prefixes to them, to the generated client-side code. You can check if I'm right viewing the generated code using developer tools of your web browser. I would suggest using the `CssClass` attribute, however, something like this won't work:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="tbl_pdcr_main" CssClass="tbl-pdcr-main"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

as the `PlaceHolder` server control does not have any visible output and is used as a place holder when we add controls at run time, so it won't generate HTML div, etc. as a result

What I would do is adding an extra CSS class to some HTML element, it can be `div` as an example (`CssClass` should also work but for different asp elements)

```
<div class="modal-body tbl-pdcr-main">
                ...
```

so the `success` part of your ajax code can just work e.g. like follows:

```
success: function (data) {
   $('.tbl-pdcr-main').text(data.d.YGec);
},
```

Comment: Using css class name is indeed a good solution. But the ClientID is designed to be used in JavaScript and his unicity is handled by asp.net. if he use css class he will need to ensure of the unicity himself.

Comment: I think this can also be a solution: `$("[id$=yourId]")` :D